# Remmina Copy-Paste issue

Tags: remote-desktop, copy-paste, remmina

I utilize the Remmina software in order to connect through the XRDP service in a remote Ubuntu server. However, I cannot use the copy-paste functions to copy information from the remote machine to my personal host and vice versa. Specifically, I use the 1.12 version of the Remmina.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.